# Why can't dd write to /dev/ram0 on Core Linux?

Tags: dd, initramfs, initrd, ramdisk, tinycore

I created an ext2 file-system on `/dev/ram0` ramdisk, and mounted it at `/mnt/ram`.

```
mkdir /mnt/ram
mkext2fs /dev/ram0
sudo mount /dev/ram0 /mnt/ram -o rw
```

Reading from ramdisk with `dd` works.

```
dd if=/dev/ram0 bs=1 count=1
```

When I want to write the contents of the file `my_file` to ramdisk, it fails.

```
dd if=./my_file of=/dev/ram0 bs=1 count=1
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0B) copied, 0.000913 seconds, 0B/s
```

However, just reading the file dumps its content on stdin.

```
dd if=./my_file bs=1 count=1
```

The permission on `/dev/ram0` shows rw permisssion for root.

```
ls -l /dev/ram0
brw-rw----   1  root   staff   1,   0   Jul   5   02:56   /dev/ram0
```

What does prevent dd from writing to `/dev/ram0`?

Comment: Im not sure that what you want to do is possible but you better mount the fs instead of trying to overwrite it